# How to Get where lightning component has been added - like small / medium/ large width area lightning account record page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want to change the height of the lightning component that has a canvas iframe in it. The lightning components controller will pass the height to my backend and I will use that to set the height of the html returned. Any idea how to find out if this lightning component was added to the small chatter side, or the very top.
In other words pass the width of the lightning component to its controller.

Comment: Why do you need to know this information? What problem are you trying to solve? This may be an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: want to make the height of the lightning component dynamic. Like if its in a small width, then height is 1000px, if its in medium then height is 800, if large then height is 600. something like that. The lightning component contains a force:canvasapp in it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you may be looking for the `lightning:flexipageRegionInfo` component:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_width_aware.htm

Cheers,